# displaying table field names dynamically with cake php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to display a list of all entries in the table people.  I have the list of entries generating correctly as a html table but I want to ad a row at the top of the table with the table field names.  I could do this manually but figure there must be a way to do it dynamically in case I add or remove fields later on.

here is the controller function

```
public function peopleDisplay() {
        $this->set('people', $this->people->find('all'));

    }
```

Are the field names already in the array that generates?  If so how do I reference them?  If not how do I get them to be?

Here is the view so far

```
    <table>

<tr>

***were I want the row of field names to go***

</tr>


<?php foreach($people as $people): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php  echo $people['people']['id'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php  echo $people['people']['firstName'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php  echo $people['people']['secondName'] ?>
            </td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Comment: `$people as $people` ? Make at least `$people as $person`

Comment: Thanks its things like that you don't really learn/catch onto while trying to teach yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column names are the keys in your array.  For instance, 'id', 'firstName', and 'secondName' are the column names.

Another way to approach would be to get the column names as a separate array in your controller and then output them in your view.

```
$people = $this->People->find('all');
$colNames = array_keys($this->People->getColumnTypes());
$this->set(compact('colNames', 'people'));
```

Then in your view:

```
foreach($colNames as $col){ //Output column names }
foreach($people as $person){ //Output people }
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.  $people is a multidimensional array, so if I just echo the keys of $people I will get 01234.... etc depending on how manly entries are in the table.  So I need to get to the array that is position 0 of the $people array and iterate over that one instead to get the column names for that entry and you can assume that the column names for every entry are the same?

Comment: Yes, people is a multidimensional array.  The point was not to iterate over that array, but that you have the columns available should you need to output them through that array.  The method, `$colNames = array_keys($this->People->getColumnTypes());`, should get the column names for you in a separate array so you can just output them directly.

Comment: Thank-you I apprecaite that code I was refering to your first line 'The column names are the keys in your array. For instance, 'id', 'firstName', and 'secondName' are the column names.'  as that seems to be the sensible thing to use seen as it is already there. instead of creating another array.  should this work? `if (isset($people[0][0])) {
 foreach($people[0][0] as $keynames => $values): {
 echo $keynames;
 
}
endforeach;
}`

Comment: I would use another array.  It makes your code easier to read and implement and it has minimal overhead.